# Setting spinner position in android

Tags: android, spinner, material-design

I use the MaterialBetterSpinner library for the spinner but not able to set to specified position.

```
String[] LIST = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"};

MaterialBetterSpinner spinnerItem = (MaterialBetterSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerItem);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, LIST);

String str = "Item3";
for(int i=0; i < adapter1.getCount(); i++) {
    if(str.trim().equals(adapter1.getItem(i).toString())){
        spinnerItem.setSelection(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

I get the below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (1 ... 1) ends beyond length 0
```

Comment: what is the content of adapter1?

Comment: Are you trying to select "Item3" by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/13) the solution is using **getText()**

So, you can have the default value doing this

```
     String[] LIST = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, LIST);

        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);


        String str = "Item3";
        for(int i=0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            if(str.trim().equals(adapter.getItem(i).toString())){
                spinner2.setText(adapter.getItem(i).toString());
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: After spending 3 hours i found the answer. Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

This is from Android Developers

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

After creating adapter you have only to call `spinner.setAdapter(adapter)` instead of each item

**EDIT:**
To set a specific item as default

```
String string = 'my string';
int spinnerPosition = adapter.getPosition(string);
spinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

**EDIT 2:**
Due to issue (https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner/issues/13) also specified by Jorge Casariego, use setText but if you know the string is in the spinner you can improve his code using only

```
spinner.setText(string)
```

Comment: With this the spinner is getting populated. But I need to set the spinner item to "Item3" when the application starts.